Wording to call an aircraft from the ground
As a student pilot I've learned how to call "traffic", ATC, and other aircraft, when necessary. However, imagine I have a portable radio on the ground and want to talk to my friend who's flying nearby in uncontrolled airspace.

When I call him on the correct frequency, should I assume I'd address him tail number initially? (Though I've heard my instructors radio each other by name.)
How would I identify myself? Is there a "proper" way to do this? In uncontrolled space on unicom, does it matter?


You mention "uncontrolled" airspace a couple times. Are you certain that your friend flying lower than 1200' AGL? Because if they're higher than that they are in fact in controlled airspace.

@randomhead, well, of course that is location dependent...

@Michael given that OP used the "usa" tag, not really. Not in the Lower 48 and not even as much these days in Alaska.

@randomhead, but there is... in some locations in the USA... class G above 1200' AGL, yes?  And for purposes of the question, does it matter?  (The radio signal doesn't recognize airspace categories...)

In two remaining very remote and (relatively) very small locations, yes. The exceptions that prove the rule.

OK, but exceptions are exactly that, exceptions.  They don't prove a rule, they disprove it.

@MichaelHall The phrase "the exception that proves the rule" means that the existence of an exception proves that the rule exists, even if it's unwritten. The fact that there are only two remote areas that you can point to that don't fit the generalization can stand as proof that the generalization is accurate.

@DarthPseudonym, I agree with you, but the comment that started this was an absolute, not a generalization...

In short
When pilots are not operating aircraft, and are not performing another aviation-related duty, they are part of the public, and are not allowed to chat with aircraft crews using the dedicated aviation frequency bands.
If they perform an aviation duty requiring a radio station, a license has been issued for this station, with the corresponding callsign. From FCC:

You may only use your hand-held aviation VHF radio from your aircraft, or under the authority of an FCC ground station authorization.


Ground station authorizations are usually only issued to aviation service organizations located on airports, businesses engaged in pilot training, aircraft manufacturers, or persons engaged in chase activities related to soaring and ballooning.


Details
FCC regulates the use of the radio spectrum. The general rule is, a few exceptions apart, frequencies are allocated to services, and services cannot be used without a specific FCC authorization (license) for:

The transmitter, this is managed by the manufacturer.

The station, to deliver or use the service. This is the license we usually talk about.

Possibly the operator, e.g. boat radio operators or ham operators. This is usually part of a certificate recognizing knowledge and skills in a broader domain.


From the previous page:

Wherever aviation services are provided in U.S. territory, both FAA and FCC requirements must be met by anyone who uses aviation radio.

The law: 47 CFR
In the domain of aeronautical transmissions, frequency bands are allocated to navaids, ATC, voice and data communications, etc. In the US, everyone is allowed to listen to radio exchanges, even private, when the channel is not encrypted. However it is forbidden to transmit without the appropriate license.
47 CFR §87.18:

Except as noted in paragraph (b) of this section, stations in the aviation service must be licensed by the FCC either individually or by fleet.

Transmitting on dedicated aviation bands is allowed from properly licensed stations, operated by authorized users. E.g. a license is issued for the use of an aircraft transmitter by crews, for the use of a ground station by ATC operators, for a FBO station, for the supporting crew of a free balloon, etc. The license is issued with a callsign allocated to the station.
Such licenses are not delivered to a person, but to the station. From $87.18:

An aircraft station is licensed by rule and does not need an individual license issued by the FCC [...]

The stations must be used to provide one of the services described in Part 87, this is the meaning of "licensed by rule": The station stops to be allowed to operate as soon as it stops to be compliant with the technical specifications of the service or is not used for the service.
Regulations are similar across the world, because FCC and FAA work with other country counterparts within ITU and ICAO UN agencies. The international principles that need to be implemented in State member regulations are agreed within these agencies.
Communications on Unicom
A pilot on the ground is not allowed to use a transmitter to chat with flying pilots on the aeronautical bands, including on Unicom, where communications have specific forms and purposes. From the page previously linked:

Aeronautical advisory stations, also called Unicom stations, are land stations used for advising pilots of private aircraft about local airport conditions.

$87.18:

Even though an individual license is not required, an aircraft station licensed by rule must be operated in accordance with all applicable operating requirements, procedures, and technical specifications found in this part.

§87.213:

Unicom transmissions must be limited to the necessities of safe and expeditious operation of aircraft such as condition of runways, types of fuel available, wind conditions, weather information, dispatching, or other necessary information.

Not for chatting with pilots.
In practical
That said, in practical the FCC is not able to enforce the corresponding regulation and transceivers are freely available.
Still if an unlawful transmission disrupts or interferes with legitimate services or causes an incident, FCC and/or FAA may investigate and take the author to a court.
Bands available to the general public for private/business use
Services/frequencies open to the general public, without constraints on the content of the message include:

Citizen Band Radio Service (CB), HF, no license required.
Family Radio Service (FRS), UHF, no license required
Multi Use Radio Service (MURS), VHF, no license required
General Mobile Radio Service (GMRS), UHF, license required

There are other services, like the radioamateur service, open to the general public, but the license is granted after passing an exam and the content of the messages is (at least on the paper) constrained to technical topics related to radio experiments.

To expand on mins answer concerning amateur radio, in the USA and in most other countries, it is relatively easy to get a amateur radio or HAM radio license. In the USA a technician license lets you use VHF and UHF hand held radios. you only have to pass a fairly simple 35 question test. Many HAM radio clubs hold testing sessions, in person or even online, and some will hold classes on the material. There are numerous training apps, websites, and books.
With books, make sure they are relatively recent, the pool of questions on the tests get updated every 5 years. Our club had a mother and son fail the test, they had studies using a 30 year book from the local library. We showed them an app for their phone they can use instead.
These are not the aviation radios installed in the airplane. They operate in the same band, but on different frequencies.
Many pilots are HAM radio operators and do use hand helds when they fly to talk to other HAMS on the ground.
You cannot install a mobile HAM radio on your plane. There are regulations on what equipment can be installed. Hand helds are OK.
CB, FRS, GMRS, and MURS can also be used and each has its own licensing requirements. Some like FRS are very restricted in power and you might have issues with making contact over any distance.

I'm aware it's a usual practice nowadays, but using the amateur service like the CB service or the other services mentioned in the answer is not the purpose of the amateur service (research, testing and disaster communication), and is indeed prohibited as: "Communications, on a regular basis, which could reasonably be furnished alternatively through other radio services." (97.113).

Ham radio certainly is used for emergency communications and there definitely are people doing  a great deal of testing and research, but most HAM radio operators are simply talking to each other. There are definitely limitations, I cannot broadcast music for example. There are limitations on frequencies and power, but two people talking to each other, or even a group of people talking to each other, is definitely legal.
